# I am getting PersonRaceCode where even though there is no code available

Tags: xml, xslt

I only want to have `<ext:PersonRaceCode>A</ext:PersonRaceCode>` for the protectedparty that is the petitioner because their `<ObservedRace Word="A">Asian</ObservedRace>` is available in xml. 
However I am getting the same `<ext:PersonRaceCode>A</ext:PersonRaceCode>`for both parties even though the other protected party does not have `<ObservedRace>`available in xml.

**Expected output:**

```
        <ext:ProtectedParty>
        <ext:PersonBirthDate ext:approximateDateIndicator="false" ext:currentIndicator="true">1969-10-14</ext:PersonBirthDate>
        <nc:PersonName>
            <nc:PersonGivenName>Jeann</nc:PersonGivenName>
            <nc:PersonMiddleName>Kume</nc:PersonMiddleName>
            <nc:PersonSurName>Dudu</nc:PersonSurName>
            <nc:PersonNameSuffixText/>
            <nc:PersonFullName>Dudu, Jeann Kume</nc:PersonFullName>
        </nc:PersonName>
        <ext:PersonRaceCode>A</ext:PersonRaceCode>
        <nc:PersonSexCode>M</nc:PersonSexCode>
        <ext:PetitionerIndicator>true</ext:PetitionerIndicator>
    </ext:ProtectedParty>
    <ext:ProtectedParty>
        <ext:PersonBirthDate ext:approximateDateIndicator="false" ext:currentIndicator="true">2001-03-15</ext:PersonBirthDate>
        <nc:PersonName>
            <nc:PersonGivenName>Brad</nc:PersonGivenName>
            <nc:PersonMiddleName/>
            <nc:PersonSurName>Mike</nc:PersonSurName>
            <nc:PersonNameSuffixText/>
            <nc:PersonFullName>Mike, Brad</nc:PersonFullName>
        </nc:PersonName>
        <ext:PersonRaceCode/>
        <nc:PersonSexCode>M</nc:PersonSexCode>
        <ext:PetitionerIndicator>false</ext:PetitionerIndicator>
    </ext:ProtectedParty>
```

**Current wrong output**

```
        <ext:ProtectedParty>
        <ext:PersonBirthDate ext:approximateDateIndicator="false" ext:currentIndicator="true">1969-10-14</ext:PersonBirthDate>
        <nc:PersonName>
            <nc:PersonGivenName>Jeann</nc:PersonGivenName>
            <nc:PersonMiddleName>Kume</nc:PersonMiddleName>
            <nc:PersonSurName>Dudu</nc:PersonSurName>
            <nc:PersonNameSuffixText/>
            <nc:PersonFullName>Dudu, Jeann Kume</nc:PersonFullName>
        </nc:PersonName>
        <ext:PersonRaceCode>A</ext:PersonRaceCode>
        <nc:PersonSexCode>M</nc:PersonSexCode>
        <ext:PetitionerIndicator>true</ext:PetitionerIndicator>
    </ext:ProtectedParty>
    <ext:ProtectedParty>
        <ext:PersonBirthDate ext:approximateDateIndicator="false" ext:currentIndicator="true">2001-03-15</ext:PersonBirthDate>
        <nc:PersonName>
            <nc:PersonGivenName>Brad</nc:PersonGivenName>
            <nc:PersonMiddleName/>
            <nc:PersonSurName>Mike</nc:PersonSurName>
            <nc:PersonNameSuffixText/>
            <nc:PersonFullName>Mike, Brad</nc:PersonFullName>
        </nc:PersonName>
        <ext:PersonRaceCode>A</ext:PersonRaceCode>
        <nc:PersonSexCode>M</nc:PersonSexCode>
        <ext:PetitionerIndicator>false</ext:PetitionerIndicator>
    </ext:ProtectedParty>
```

**My xml code**

```
<Integration xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:tsg="http://tsgweb.com" xmlns:IXML="http://tsgweb.com">
    <Case InternalID="1616758956" ID="11682320" xmlns:user="http://tylertechnologies.com">
        <CaseParty ID="14374736" InternalCasePartyID="1633583492" InternalPartyID="1612267260">
            <SendNotice>true</SendNotice>
            <ObservedRace Word="A">Asian</ObservedRace>
            <Connection Word="PET" BaseConnection="PL" ID="34643485" InternalCasePartyConnectionID="1635190996">
                <Description>Petitioner</Description>
            </Connection>
            <CasePartyName Current="true" ID="4990971" InternalNameID="1612653737">
                <NameType>Standard</NameType>
                <NameFirst>Jeann</NameFirst>
                <NameMiddle>Kume</NameMiddle>
                <NameLast>Dudu</NameLast>
                <FormattedName>Dudu, Jeann Kume</FormattedName>
            </CasePartyName>
        </CaseParty>
        <CaseParty ID="16548387" InternalCasePartyID="1633583509" InternalPartyID="1614451524">
            <SendNotice>true</SendNotice>
            <Connection Word="MNR" BaseConnection="O2" ID="34643502" InternalCasePartyConnectionID="1635191013">
                <Description>Minor</Description>
            </Connection>
            <CasePartyName Current="true" ID="9638900" InternalNameID="1615262962">
                <NameType>Standard</NameType>
                <NameFirst>Brad</NameFirst>
                <NameLast>Mike</NameLast>
                <FormattedName>Mike, Brad</FormattedName>
            </CasePartyName>
        </CaseParty>
        <ProtectionOrders>
            <ProtectionOrder Op="E" InternalProtectionOrderID="1349">
                <Deleted>false</Deleted>
                <RespondentPartyID InternalPartyID="1610253026">1610253026</RespondentPartyID>
                <RespondentNameID InternalNameID="1610281862">1610281862</RespondentNameID>
                <ProtectionOrderNumber>1400350</ProtectionOrderNumber>
                <ProtectionOrderParties>
                    <ProtectionOrderParty InternalPartyID="1612267260">
                        <ProtectionOrderPartyNames>
                            <ProtectionOrderPartyName Current="true" InternalNameID="1612653737" FormattedName="Dudu, Jeann Kume"/>
                        </ProtectionOrderPartyNames>
                        <ProtectionOrderConnection>
                            <Petitioner>true</Petitioner>
                            <ProtectedParty>true</ProtectedParty>
                            <Minor>false</Minor>
                        </ProtectionOrderConnection>
                    </ProtectionOrderParty>
                    <ProtectionOrderParty InternalPartyID="1614451524">
                        <ProtectionOrderPartyNames>
                            <ProtectionOrderPartyName Current="true" InternalNameID="1615262962" FormattedName="Mike, Brad"/>
                        </ProtectionOrderPartyNames>
                        <ProtectionOrderConnection>
                            <Petitioner>false</Petitioner>
                            <ProtectedParty>true</ProtectedParty>
                            <Minor>true</Minor>
                        </ProtectionOrderConnection>
                    </ProtectionOrderParty>
                </ProtectionOrderParties>
            </ProtectionOrder>
        </ProtectionOrders>
    </Case>
    <Party ID="14374736" InternalPartyID="1612267260">
        <Gender Word="M ">Male</Gender>
        <Race Word="W">White</Race>
        <DateOfBirth Current="true">10/14/1969</DateOfBirth>
        <PartyName ID="4990971" Current="true" InternalNameID="1612653737">
            <NameType>Standard</NameType>
            <NameFirst>Jeann</NameFirst>
            <NameMiddle>Kume</NameMiddle>
            <NameLast>Dudu</NameLast>
            <FormattedName>Dudu, Jeann Kume</FormattedName>
        </PartyName>
    </Party>
    <Party ID="16548387" InternalPartyID="1614451524">
        <Gender Word="M ">Male</Gender>
        <DateOfBirth Current="true">03/15/2001</DateOfBirth>
        <PartyName ID="9638900" Current="true" InternalNameID="1615262962">
            <NameType>Standard</NameType>
            <NameFirst>Brad</NameFirst>
            <NameLast>Mike</NameLast>
            <FormattedName>Mike, Brad</FormattedName>
        </PartyName>
    </Party>
    <IntegrationConditions>
        <IntegrationCondition>
            <NotificationEvent internalProtectionOrderID="1349" protectionOrderNumber="1400350" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">Signed</NotificationEvent>
        </IntegrationCondition>
    </IntegrationConditions>
</Integration>
```

My xslt code has two templates for **protected party** and **petitioner**. A petitioner can also be a protected party which means not all petitioners are protected parties and not all protected parties are petitioners.

**xslt code**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ext="http://www.courts.state.mn.us/ProtectionOrderExtension/1.0" xmlns:nc="http://niem.gov/niem/niem-core/2.0" exclude-result-prefixes="mscef msxsl exsl">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template name="ProtectionOrder">
        <ext:ProtectionOrder>
            <xsl:variable name="vProtectionOrderID">
                <xsl:value-of select="@InternalProtectionOrderID"/>
            </xsl:variable>
<!--Petitioner-->
            <xsl:for-each select="ProtectionOrderParties/ProtectionOrderParty[(ProtectionOrderConnection/Petitioner='true') and (ProtectionOrderConnection/ProtectedParty='false')][1]">
                <xsl:for-each select="//Integration/Party[@InternalPartyID=current()/@InternalPartyID]">
                    <xsl:call-template name="Petitioner"/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
<!--Protected Party-->
            <xsl:for-each select="ProtectionOrderParties/ProtectionOrderParty[ProtectionOrderConnection/ProtectedParty='true']">
                <xsl:variable name="vPetitionerIndicator">
                    <xsl:value-of select="ProtectionOrderConnection/Petitioner"/>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:for-each select="//CaseParty[(@InternalPartyID=current()/@InternalPartyID)]">
                    <!--<xsl:for-each select="//Integration/Party[@InternalPartyID=current()/@InternalPartyID]">-->
                    <xsl:for-each select="//Integration/Party[@InternalPartyID=current()/@InternalPartyID]">
                        <xsl:call-template name="ProtectedParty">
                            <xsl:with-param name="pPetionerIndicator">
                                <xsl:value-of select="$vPetitionerIndicator"/>
                            </xsl:with-param>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>

<!--ext:ProtectionOrderID-->
            <ext:ProtectionOrderID>
                <xsl:value-of select="ProtectionOrderNumber"/>
            </ext:ProtectionOrderID>
<!--ext:ProtectionOrderTypeCode-->
            <ext:ProtectionOrderTypeCode>
                <xsl:value-of select="Type/@Word"/>
            </ext:ProtectionOrderTypeCode>
        </ext:ProtectionOrder>
    </xsl:template>
<!--Protection order template ends here-->
<!--Petitioner Template-->
    <xsl:template name="Petitioner">
        <ext:Petitioner>
            <ext:AddressReference>
                <xsl:for-each select="Address[@PartyCurrent='true']">
                    <xsl:attribute name="ext:currentIndicator"><xsl:value-of select="@PartyCurrent"/></xsl:attribute>
                    <nc:LocationReference>
                        <xsl:attribute name="s:ref"><xsl:text>INT</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="@ID"/></xsl:attribute>
                    </nc:LocationReference>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </ext:AddressReference>
            <ext:PersonBirthDate>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="DateOfBirth[@Current='true']">
                        <xsl:attribute name="ext:approximateDateIndicator">false</xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="ext:currentIndicator">true</xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:value-of select="mscef:formatDate(string(DateOfBirth[@Current='true']))"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="ApproximateDOB">
                        <xsl:attribute name="ext:approximateDateIndicator">true</xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="ext:currentIndicator">true</xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:value-of select="mscef:formatDate(string(ApproximateDOB))"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                </xsl:choose>
            </ext:PersonBirthDate>
            <nc:PersonName>
                <nc:PersonGivenName>
                    <xsl:value-of select="PartyName/NameFirst"/>
                </nc:PersonGivenName>
                <nc:PersonMiddleName>
                    <xsl:value-of select="PartyName/NameMiddle"/>
                </nc:PersonMiddleName>
                <nc:PersonSurName>
                    <xsl:value-of select="PartyName/NameLast"/>
                </nc:PersonSurName>
                <nc:PersonNameSuffixText>
                    <!--<xsl:value-of select="PartyName/NameSuffix/@Word"/>-->
                    <xsl:value-of select="PartyName/NameSuffix"/>
                </nc:PersonNameSuffixText>
                <nc:PersonFullName>
                    <xsl:value-of select="PartyName/FormattedName"/>
                </nc:PersonFullName>
            </nc:PersonName>
            <ext:PersonRaceCode>
                <!--<xsl:value-of select="/Integration/Case/CaseParty[1]/ObservedRace/@Word"/>-->
                <xsl:value-of select="/Integration/Case/CaseParty/ObservedRace/@Word"/>
            </ext:PersonRaceCode>
            <nc:PersonSexCode>
                <xsl:value-of select="Party/Gender/@Word"/>
            </nc:PersonSexCode>
        </ext:Petitioner>
    </xsl:template>
<!--Protected Party Template-->
    <xsl:template name="ProtectedParty">
        <xsl:param name="pPetionerIndicator"/>
        <ext:ProtectedParty>
            <ext:PersonBirthDate>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="DateOfBirth[@Current='true']">
                        <xsl:attribute name="ext:approximateDateIndicator">false</xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="ext:currentIndicator">true</xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:value-of select="mscef:formatDate(string(DateOfBirth[@Current='true']))"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="ApproximateDOB">
                        <xsl:attribute name="ext:approximateDateIndicator">true</xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="ext:currentIndicator">true</xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:value-of select="mscef:formatDate(string(ApproximateDOB))"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                </xsl:choose>
            </ext:PersonBirthDate>
            <xsl:for-each select="PartyName[@Current='true']">
                <nc:PersonName>
                    <nc:PersonGivenName>
                        <xsl:value-of select="NameFirst"/>
                    </nc:PersonGivenName>
                    <nc:PersonMiddleName>
                        <xsl:value-of select="NameMiddle"/>
                    </nc:PersonMiddleName>
                    <nc:PersonSurName>
                        <xsl:value-of select="NameLast"/>
                    </nc:PersonSurName>
                    <nc:PersonNameSuffixText>
                        <xsl:value-of select="NameSuffix"/>
                    </nc:PersonNameSuffixText>
                    <nc:PersonFullName>
                        <xsl:value-of select="FormattedName"/>
                    </nc:PersonFullName>
                </nc:PersonName>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <ext:PersonRaceCode>
                <!--<xsl:value-of select="/Integration/Case/CaseParty/ObservedRace/@Word"/>-->
                <xsl:value-of select="/Integration/Case/CaseParty/ObservedRace/@Word"/>
            </ext:PersonRaceCode>
            <nc:PersonSexCode>
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(Gender/@Word)"/>
            </nc:PersonSexCode>
            <ext:PetitionerIndicator>
                <xsl:value-of select="$pPetionerIndicator"/>
            </ext:PetitionerIndicator>
        </ext:ProtectedParty>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to look for  ObservedRace Word= 'A' then your condition should be

```
<xsl:value-of select="/Integration/Case/CaseParty/ObservedRace/@Word[. = 'A']"/>
```

it will print the attribute 'Word' value, which is A.

Comment: But will that work when ObservedRace Word ='H', or 'W'? I am asking because the Observed race can be some other letter other than 'A' And I changed my code but it is still printing ObservedRace = A for the party without ObservedRace element.

Comment: It wont work if you have other letters. In that case
 <ext:PersonRaceCode>
               
                <xsl:if test="/Integration/Case/CaseParty/ObservedRace/@Word != ''">
  <xsl:value-of select="/Integration/Case/CaseParty/ObservedRace/@Word"/>
  </xsl:if>
         
            </ext:PersonRaceCode>

i tested it, its just printing only for Asian.

Comment: Actually for some reason this did not work for me. What I did was to make sure I am using current like this...           `<ext:PersonRaceCode>
<xsl:value-of select="//Case/CaseParty[@InternalPartyID=current()/@InternalPartyID]/ObservedRace/@Word"/>
</ext:PersonRaceCode>` and it is now working for any code.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did and it is working. Including current makes sure that it will get the PersonRaceCode for each CaseParty. Without current, it only take the first caseparty and add that to any other caseparty available.

```
<ext:PersonRaceCode> 
<xsl:value-of select="//Case/CaseParty[@InternalPartyID=current()/@InternalPartyID]/ObservedRa‌​ce/@Word"/> 
</ext:PersonRaceCode>
```